# How to test side effect of the method which raises error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a method like:

```
def method
  # ..
  begin
    some_invokation
  rescue StandardError
    # some_other_stuff
    raise
  end
  # ..
  User.create!
end
```

Right now I can test that this method raises the exception:

```
expect { method }.to raise_error(StandardError)
```

But also I would like to test that the user is not created.

```
expect { method }.not_to change { User.count }
```

It doesn't work. It shows that the exception was raised. I tried to mock raise invocation:

```
allow_any_instance_of(described_class).to receive(:raise)
```

But in this case my `method` is not interrupted and the user is created. Are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
expect { 
  method rescue nil
}.not_to change { User.count }
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do it:

```
expect { method }.to raise_error(StandardError)
expect { method rescue 'method rescued' }.to eq('method rescued')
expect { method rescue 'method rescued' }.not_to change { User.count }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
expect { robot.greet }.to raise_error
```

you can method stub the `raise` to prevent it from breaking the other examples:

```
class Robot
  def greet
    puts 'Hello World'
    raise 'malfunction'
  end
end
```

```
RSpec.describe Robot do
  let(:robot) { Robot.new }

  describe '#greet' do
    before do
      allow(robot).to receive(:puts)
      allow(robot).to receive(:raise)
      robot.greet
    end

    it 'prints a message to console' do
      expect(robot).to have_received(:puts).with('Hello World')
    end

    it 'malfunctions' do
      expect(robot).to have_received(:raise)
    end
  end
end
```